# how formulate a query in deezer iOS API in order to get a specific song with artist and title?

Tags: ios, deezer

how formulate a query in deezer iOs api in order to get a specific song with artist and title?

I've seen the code on the documentation but i don't get the use of:

```
NSString* servicePath =@"album/12345";
DeezerRequest* request = [deezerConnect createRequestWithServicePath:servicePath
                               params:nil delegate:self];  
[deezerConnect launchAsyncRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query anything that's available in the Deezer API so you can check our API explorer for further reference: http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer

To get info about a particular song, just make a query on @"track/TRACKID" for example "track/3135556"

Comment: thanks but my problem was that I didn't have the track ID.
solve with a search method and checking the parameters 'type','title' and 'artist'